csv writer twice adds double quotes to python
I have written a py script that takes in a csv file, validates and corrects it. The problem is that the result is not as expected. The resulted content of the fixed file has got extra double quotes instead of single. Any suggestion how to fix this? Below is the snippet:
import csv

def process_csv():
    fixed_file_path = "C:\\files\\testing\\testing.csv"
    with open(fixed_file_path, mode="w", encoding="utf-8", newline='') as fixed_file:
        writer = csv.writer(fixed_file, delimiter=";")
        row = 'Path 2;"my text";red;2024-04-02T04:04:49;'
        writer.writerow([row])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_csv()

the output then looks like this: "Path 2;""my text"";red;2024-04-02T04:04:49;"
why does it add the extra double quotes to the "my text"?
I tried using quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar=None, escapechar=None but then I get an error message saying: _csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
I am using python version 3.11.3

You are writing a single column into the row. As it contains quotes they need to be escaped. If you want to write multiple columns use it like this: writer.writerow(['Path 2', '"my text"', 'red', '2024-04-02T04:04:49', '']) - i put an empty string at the end since you put a separator there.

If your string is already CSV syntax, you don't need the csv module to write it to a file. Just write it plainly into a file.

I hope I understood your question correctly and this answer will solve your problem. Otherwise, provide a clearer explanation with more examples.
change process_csv method to this:
def process_csv():
    fixed_file_path = "C:\\files\\testing\\testing.csv"
    with open(fixed_file_path, mode="w", encoding="utf-8", newline='') as fixed_file:
        writer = csv.writer(fixed_file, delimiter=";")
        row = 'Path 2;my text;red;2024-04-02T04:04:49;'
        writer.writerow([row])

There is no need to put double quotes for [my text].
